# understanding error "value cannot be null" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am learning ASP.NET MVC 2, and I am concentrating on "Ajax and Client scripting".

I have written the code like below just by following the book:

```
public class MVCAJAXLearningsController : Controller
{
    private Dictionary<string, double> offsets = new Dictionary<string, double> { { "utc", 0 }, { "bst", 1 }, { "mdt", -6 }, { "ist", 5.5 } };

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetTime(string zone)
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(offsets[zone]);
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            string fragment = string.Format("<div>The time in {0} is {1:hh:MM:ss tt}</div>", zone.ToUpper(), time);
            return Content(fragment);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(time);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error.

[image: ***Error***]

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% but you don't seem to be passing a parameter to GetTime.

Comment: +1: Specifically, the "zone" parameter is not getting populated.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. Yes!, you are right(I guess). How can I pass parameter? Can you please suggest me...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your code. There are libraries included in the MVC projects that are used for submitting back to the controller that are not referenced in your master page.

If you look in your Scripts folder, you will see two javascrip libraries called MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js. Both of these need to be loaded when the project is running.

Simply add these two lines into the  section of your site master page:

```
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After that, you should be good to go.

Try this and see if it helps.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I have already done like this. But, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

What parameter value do you send to the action?  An example in razor:
@{Html.Renderaction("GetTime", "MVCAJAXLearnings", new {zone= "ist"});}